# How can a Caliburn.Micro sub menuitem click call an action on the containing view's viewmodel?

Tags: menuitem, caliburn.micro

I have a top level menu in my ShellView and when selecting a sub MenuItem, I would like to call the following method on the ShellViewModel (a Conductor.Collection.AllActive).

```
    public void SelectServer(string pServerName)
    {
        mDefaultClaimServer = pServerName;
    }
```

The following does not work as no method gets called (I have tried various signatures and action parameters) -

```
    <Menu Name="menu1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Select Server" Name="ClaimServers">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- we need this else we show the class name -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}">
                        <ContentControl cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action TxTester.ShellViewModel.SelectServer($Text)]"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

The following does call the ShellViewModel SelectServer method but I get null for the text of the clicked sub MenuItem (I also tried many other signatures and action parameters) -

```
    <Menu Name="menu1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Select Server" Name="ClaimServers" cal:Message.Attach="SelectServer($this.Text)">
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- we need this else we show the class name -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

I've been struggling with this a long time and can't figure it out. Can someone suggest the proper combination where I can pass the header text of a sub MenuItem to the ShellViewModel SelectServer method?

Comment: Won't Menu fire SelectionChanged or have a SelectedItem property to bind too.

Comment: Derek - I'm trying to avoid code behind tied to events by using CM mechanisms (and also trying to learn CM).

Comment: Sure but an action can be used for this.

Comment: I could call actions just fine but could not find a parameter to pass that would deliver me the MenuItem text (I tried Text as an argument and my action got called but the argument was null). I tried what I could think of. Do you know which would have done it? I'm still pretty new at CM and only got the below to work. Probably just did it wrong...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got what I was trying to do working, per a post from Rob Eisenberg describing a "special trick to get the text from bound submenus" here - http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/287228

I would still love to know how to do what I was trying to do with standard OOTB logic if anyone has suggestions, so that I am able to understand CM better.

Basically I added this to the bootstrapper Configure() overide -

```
        MessageBinder.SpecialValues.Add("$originalsourcecontext", context =>
        {
            var args = context.EventArgs as RoutedEventArgs;
            if (args == null)
                return null;

            var fe = args.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe == null)
                return null;

            return fe.DataContext;
        });
```

and added this to the xaml -

```
        <MenuItem Header="_Select Server" Name="ClaimServers" cal:Message.Attach="SelectServer($originalsourcecontext)" />
```

and then I was passed the header text of the sub menuitem which is what I wanted.