# Attach to Click even when the item is created using a concention

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I would like to transform a view model's collection to a list of menu items and then get notified when user click on a menu item. I have created a view model for the menu item and bound the collection as shown bellow. Unfortunately, I have difficulties in finding a way how to attach a method to the Click event of the created menu items.

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding SampleMenuItems}"/>
</Menu>


public class MenuItemModel
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Sample item";
    }

    public void Click()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

What should I change to get the Click() method called when the user clicks on the menu item was created by Caliburn.Micro for that model instance?
/ The method name is not fixed, so it can be renamed. /

Comment: What is a "concention"?

Comment: The click event needs to be handled by the UI, not the business domain model.

Comment: In the mean time, I have found another possible solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279443/how-can-a-caliburn-micro-sub-menuitem-click-call-an-action-on-the-containing-vie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ICommand`s instead of `Click` handlers... you can use the [`MenuItem.Command` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.command(v=vs.110).aspx) for this:

```
public class MenuItemModel
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Sample item";
    }

    public void ICommand Click { get; set; }
}
```

It is also preferable to use a [`RelayCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) implementation when using `ICommand`s in this way. You can then hook them up like this:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.Click, RelativeSource={
        RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}" />
</Style>
```